# JMS Serializer unable to handle serialization loop

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Last night, my web app died with white screen being returned to a user. It didn't take very long to find out the root case: `PHP` was running out of memory.

After tracing the problem, I concluded that `JMS Serializer` failed to handle serialization loop.

I have class `ProductGroup` which has number of `Product` objects (list). Now, each `Product` refers to a group that it belongs to. So, when user tries to serialize `ProductGroup`, it does that, then proceeds to serialize each `Product` when it jumps back to `ProductGroup` (which was just serialized) effectively creating a serialization loop.

I managed to fix that but putting `@Exclude` on `Product::group` property.

**So, the question is**: Do I have another option when it comes to serializing? Is it possible that `JMS Serializer` is not capable of figuring out the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting `MaxDepth` on ProductGroup->products and Product->group to ensure it won't go into a loop. Also using your approach with different serialization groups for groups + product and product + group could mitigate this and ensure that you can still have the associated group when fetching a single product.

Regarding your second question, having a references in both directions is even discouraged in Doctrine, so JMS\Serializer throwing some kind of Exception instead of trying to "fix" it seems like expected behaviour.

Comment: I see. Well, `MaxDepth` is closest to what I can ask of it I guess :) Thanks! As for the relation, it really is single inversed `OneToMany`. If I had two separate but valid references going back and forth I assume that would be a big problem :)